# Meteor gets rid of password data when using Accounts.onCreateUser()

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I create a new user using the {{>loginButtons}} template and accounts-password, and am successfully logged in, but when I log out and attempt to log back in with the password that I'd set, I get the "User has no password set" error.

I have the following code in accountsServer.js in my server folder:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function (user, options) {
  someCollection.insert({
    name: user.username,
    elo: 1500,
  });
  return user;
});
```

And I have set up a USERNAME_ONLY config option in accountsClient.js in my client folder:

```
Accounts.ui.config({
    passwordSignupFields: "USERNAME_ONLY"
});
```

Can anybody help me out? When I comment out the code entirely in the Accounts.onCreateUser() function, the error goes away, so I'm thinking this is the root of the problem but I'm not sure what's causing it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's due to [this](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_oncreateuser):

> The default create user function simply copies `options.profile` into
>   the new user document. Calling `onCreateUser` overrides the default
>   hook. This can only be called once.

Therefore, your user creation no longer copies the options in your user before registering it. **Also, your arguments `options` and `user` seem inverted!!**

You could just add this logic back this way:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function (options, user) {
  someCollection.insert({
    name: user.username,
    elo: 1500,
  });
  if (options.profile)
    user.profile = options.profile;
  return user;
});
```

Comment: Although the remark is correct, I think the suggestion about the profile has nothing to do with the problem. The `username` field does not reside in the profile and password is hashed and stored in `services.password.bcrypt`. Inverting `options` and `user` as in the question is definitively causing problems. The insert in someCollection might fail and lead to an exception. As a result the user will not be created. My question is, does the user exist at all in the users collection?

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly my problem